# grep/awk specific lines based on specific fields; using ksh variable with awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have this input file: **file_in.txt** (delimited by pipe)

```
3345:tyg|rty|27|0|0|ty6|{89|io|}62|0
3346:tyg|rtyuio|63|0|1|ty6|{89|gh|}45|0
3347:tyu|ray|24|0|0|ty6|{89|uh|}27|0
3348:tyg|rtoy|93|0|1|ty6|{89|yh|}1|0
3349:tyo|rtert|28|0|0|ty6|{89|gh|}27|0
```

I want to get only those lines which have 9th field value as `}27` using `'|'` as delimiter so that my output should be:

```
3347:tyu|ray|24|0|0|ty6|{89|uh|}27|0
3349:tyo|rtert|28|0|0|ty6|{89|gh|}27|0
```

Below command works fine:

```
awk -F"|" '{ if ($9 == "}27") print $0 }' file_in.txt
```

But I want to use a shell variable instead of `"}27"` for which I tried this:

```
taskid="}27"    
awk -v tid="$taskid" -F"|" '{ if ($9 == "}tid") print $0 }' file_in.txt
```

Please help me figure out where I am going wrong with this command.
Any other command suggestions to achieve the same are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
taskid="}27"    
awk -v tid="$taskid" -F"|" '$9 == tid' file_in.txt
```

- default action is to print the line.
- you don't need to enclose the variable.